# SMS sent to shortcode from J2ME doesn't get reply from service. Why?

Tags: java-me, sms, shortcode, series-40

I'm building a J2ME app for Nokia Series 40 devices that has the feature of sending SMSs to predefined shrotcodes.

On some networks:
1) User uses the app, activates the send to SMS to shortcode feature, the SMS is sent and the service replies with a "Welcome" service messages.

On other networks (Same phone different SIM):
1) User uses the app, activates the send to SMS to shortcode feature, the SMS is sent and the service DOES NOT reply with a "Welcome" service messages.
2) When sending the same SMS by-hand from the Messaging application, the service DOES reply with a "Welcome" service messages

Why does this happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try, using different textboxes for each, mine did that but using unique interfaces for each and storing the shortcode adresses in arrays then traversing them worked.
Regards,
Sam